# onSelect on datepicker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to make a javascript function call when a date is selected, the javascript is as follows,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
    var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
    date_input.datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        container: container,
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            getdsr(dateText);
        }
    })
})
```

The html for the date is as follows,

```
<input id="txtdate" class="form-control" name="date" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD" type="text"  required>
```

for some reason the onselect is not working.

Comment: What library are you using to get this datepicker functionality? jQuery UI?

Comment: I am using bootstrap-datepicker.min.js for datepicker

Comment: [This one](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker)? There are so many Bootstrap datepickers out there....

Comment: An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be very helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      var date_input=$('#txtdate'); //our date input has the name "date"
      var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
      $('#txtdate').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        container: container,
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {

        //getdsr(dateText);
          console.log(dateText);
        }
      })
 })
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<input id="txtdate" class="form-control" name="date" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD" type="text"  required/>
```

Comment: Thank you, It is working now. There was an issue with the proper js.

Answer (score 0):

*onSelect* is for JQuery datepicker. Here [bootstrap datepicker docs](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it have some *changeDate* etc events that you can catch with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
      $('#txtdate').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        container: container,
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
          alert(dateText);
        }
      })
 })
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<input id="txtdate" class="form-control" name="date" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD" type="text"  required/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            alert(dateText);
        }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

</body>
</html>
```